# Find timestamps of videos split using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am able successfully able to split a video with FFmpeg using the below command

`ffmpeg -i Sample.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 900 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 output%03d.mp4`

This will split videos into 15 mins chunks (900 seconds) however this is not 100% accurate.

Is there a way to add the starting and ending timestamp of each segment, in the output file name, relative to the original file? Or generate a file containing the timestamps?

I want to know exactly where the cuts where made. I do not want to slow down the process though by forcing FFmpeg to cut at exactly 15 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the timestamps by using the segment_list and segment_list_options flag.

Using the below command you will get a CSV file containing the segment_filename,segment_start_time,segment_end_time

```
ffmpeg -i Sample.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_list sample.csv -segment_time 10 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 outputAs%03d.mp4
```

Or to get a text file with the same details you can use the command:

```
ffmpeg -i Sample.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_list sample.txt -segment_list_type csv  -segment_time 1000 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 spa%03d.mp4
```

segment_list_type with option csv generated these details. If your extension is csv for the segment_list then segment_list_type automatically is csv.